# how to import CheckboxChangeEvent in my Typescript code

Tags: typescript, antd

I want to import the `CheckboxChangeEvent` interface into my typescript file.
Although importing other antd elements is as simple as:

```
import {Checkbox} from 'antd'
```

... for the `CheckboxChangeEvent` after some grepping I resorted to doing:

```
import {CheckboxChangeEvent} from '../../../node_modules/antd/es/checkbox'
```

... where of course the number of parent path components (`..`) depends on how deep I am in my source tree structure. Regardless, this seems to be the only way to make it work.

I've tried:

```
import {CheckboxChangeEvent} from 'antd/checkbox'; 
import {CheckboxChangeEvent} from 'antd/checkbox/Checkbox';
```

... and some other permutations and they all fail.

Is there a better way?

Comment: if CheckboxChangeEvent is exported, may be webpack alias can do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

success!

```js
import type { CheckboxChangeEvent } from 'antd/es/checkbox'
```

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/7bd78e7156e0101a6d635b174751b3b686a066ab/components/checkbox/demo/basic.md

Answer (score 0):

This PR exports some common types, and it has a review comment that `CheckboxChangeEvent` should also be exported, but it was never done before PR completion.

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/pull/28963/files